# Add a custom fee only to new customers on their first order in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am having trouble using the following code with the latest version of WooCommerce.

Here is the code that I use:

```php
function custom_add_cart_fee() {
   $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );
    // Count number of orders
    $count = count( $customer_orders );

    if ( $count == 0 ) 
    {
         WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'Joining Fee', 'your-plugin'), 100 );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_add_cart_fee' );
```

What changes should I make, to make it work in latest WooCommerce?

Comment: What version was it written for? What changed between those versions? What errors do you get? Why don’t you show us the errors?

Answer (score 0):

For WooCommerce, it is better to use [`wc_get_orders()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) as orders will have very soon their own tables in the WordPress database. Now you can check if a customer has already purchased (has at least one order):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_joining_fee' );
function add_custom_joining_fee( $cart ) {
    // Dont run this in backend
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Ensure that this action is triggered only once
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Check if customer has already purchased (has at least one order)
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(), // Get user Id
        'status'   => wc_get_is_paid_statuses(), // Order status (processing and completed)
        'limit'    => 1, // One order
        'return'   => 'ids', // return only order Ids
    ) );

    if ( empty($customer_orders) ) 
    {
         $cart->add_fee( __( 'Joining Fee', 'woocommerce'), 100 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.